# Getting JS error using ng-bind-html and $sce.trustAsHtml()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS controller I have this scope function:

```
$scope.show_description = function () {
    return ($scope.details.description.length) ? $sce.trustAsHtml(newlinesFilter($scope.details.description)) : 'edit to enter a description';
};
```

The values of $scope.details.description initially has text with endlines, which the newlinesFilter replaces with BR.

```
app.filter('newlines', [function () {
    return function(text){
       return text.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
}
}]);
```

In my HTML:

```
<span ng-bind-html="show_description()"></span>
```

Everything seems to work properly, yet I get this trace error in the console:

```
Error: [$sce:unsafe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$sce/unsafe
at Error (native)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:6:450
at e (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:114:160)
at getTrusted (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:115:443)
at Object.e.(anonymous function) [as getTrustedHtml] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:117:175)
at Object.fn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:188:375)
at h.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:106:311)
at h.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:109:287)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:18:23
at Object.d [as invoke] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:34:265) angular.js:9778
```

Comment: Seems to be working ok here: http://plnkr.co/edit/bBfXUOENQrBKABMhtSwy?p=preview  The only thing I changed was to wrap the whole return value in `$sce.trustAsHtml`.

Comment: Double wrapping in $sce.trustAsHtml() did the trick. return $sce.trustAsHtml(($scope.details.description.length) ? $filter('newlines')($scope.details.description) : 'edit to enter a description');

Comment: Cool.  I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `show_description()` function, you want to run all return values through `$sce.trustAsHtml()`, not just the non-default value.  So modify the return statement like this:

```
return $sce.trustAsHtml(($scope.details.description.length) ? $filter('newlines')($scope.details.description) : 'edit to enter a description');
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bBfXUOENQrBKABMhtSwy?p=preview)